# Is new Stack<T>(curStack) returns reverse stack a bug?

Tags: c#, stack

This would appear to be a bug. Consider the following:
[image: stack order: skip skip match]

... then:
[image: stack order: match skip skip]

After doing some checking, I found [this answer as to some 'reversal' in stack order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215172/210709).

Wouldn't it be proper to expect the second stack to be in the same order as the original?
Is this a bug?

Comment: I have no idea what these screenshots mean.  Consider constructing a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) to explore/demonstrate what you're talking about...

Comment: Don't exactly understand the question from the data given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

A stack will yield the most recently added item first.  So when you go to populate the new stack you're adding the newest item first.  Since this item is added first it will now be the "oldest" item in the new stack, even though it was the "newest" item in the old stack.

The reversing is entirely expected behavior.

If you had a queue, then writing `var newQueue = new Queue<T>(oldQueue);` would effectively create a copy.  Queues yield the oldest item first, so the oldest item in the old queue becomes the oldest item in the new queue.  The same would be true of a list as well.

You seem to be under the impression that there is some sort of copy constructor, in which the stack takes another stack and makes a copy.  This is untrue, it simply accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` as its input.  For `List` and `Queue` this has the effect of taking a copy, for stacks is simply has the effect of reversing the items.

Answer (score 2):

It's by design.

Notice that the [constructor overload of `Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you are using expects a `IEnumerable<T>`. The way it works is by iterating over the `IEnumarable<T>` and adding the items to the Stack.

Now, you are passing another `Stack<T>` as parameter. The way `IEnumerable<T>` is expected to behave is by giving the items in the order they would come when you take them from the Stack (That is LIFO: Last-In First-Out).

So, in fact, this operations are expected to reverse the stack.